# Why $L(f(t))=f(0)$ is not a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem statement:

*Let $L$ be the linear transformation from $P_{1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by*

$$L(f(t))=f(0)$$

This the explanation why it is not a linear transformation:

$$L(0)\neq L(t)$$

$$0\neq 1$$

How I can know the evaluation for $L(0)$ and $L(t)$? Why $0$ and $1$?

Comment: The notation $L(f(t))$ is confusing; I would suggest one of $L(f)$ or perhaps $L(f(\cdot))$, if you must make it explicit that $f$ is a function.

Comment: This all makes no sense at all. You say the problem statement says "Let $L$ be the linear transformation..." and then you say "This the explanation why it is not a linear transformation". What does the problem _ask_. And what do you mean, "the explanation"? Is that explanation part of the problem, or something your friend said or what?

Answer (score 2):

If $P_1$ is any vector space of functions $D\to\Bbb R$ where the set $D$ contains $0$ as element (there is nothing special about $0$ here, it could be any other element of $D$) and the vector space structure on $P_1$ is - as usual -  given by pointwise addition/multiplication, then surely $L\colon f\mapsto f(0)$ is a linear transformation $P_1\to \Bbb R$. Indeed, $L(f+g)=f(0)+g(0)=L(f)+L(g)$ and $L(cf)=c\cdot f(0)=cL(f)$.